# Evolution from year to year in text sets

Tags: clustering, text-mining, natural-language, differences

Say that we collected some essays last year and we collect other essays this year.

The goal is to apply machine learning and NLP to analyze the overall difference/tendency.

How to do that?

**First attempt**

To run TF-IDF on both sets, do cluster analysis, quantify the presence of essays in individual clusters. The result will be a table where rows are clusters and columns are years.

Are you aware of anything more sophisticated?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve that, but it mainly depends on what you are looking for. Some ideas of increasing complexity. 
Start by calculating and comparing different co-efficients:

- Number of words/essay, Number of different words/per (vocabulary richness), use of punctuation, length of sentences etc. Such measures provide a high-level comparison
- Find the N most common words (excl. stop-words) and compare them. If very different it probably suggests that language patterns change.
- Find the top (%) words, normalize them (thus obtaining probability distributions) and calculate similary, e.g., KL divergence
- train a topic model on the collection or even better on an external collection to avoid your collection bias, and examine which topics appear most and draw your comparison there.